# Tiny little but annoying error on image hover

Tags: css, hover, overlay

I'm putting the finishing touches on my portfolio website but I have some last minute annoying errors that needs to be fixed.

Here's a working example of my frontpage:
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/buch/buchstudio.html

I have this hover effect on the images but in Chrome the black overlay doesn't cover the whole image until a short second to late resulting in an ugly vertical "gap". This is only a problem with the middle images. A little hard to explain but I hope the screenshot makes sense:
[image: http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/chrome_overlay_error.jpg]

I should properly mention that I'm on a Mac.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Here's the code

```
<section class="project_main_container">
    <ul class="clearfix">       
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
            <a href="projects/spis.html"><div class="project_media">    
                <img class="project_image" src="img/thumbs/thumbs_1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="project_text">
                <h4>Spis</h4>
                <p class="project_tags">A cookbook</p>
            </div>
            </a>
            </div>
        </li>       
    </ul>      
</section>


.project_media:after{
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(24,24,24,1);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    }

.project_container:hover .project_media:after{
    opacity: 1;
    }

.project_main_container {
    width: 100%;
    }

 .project_container {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.project_container .project_text {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    width:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;

    }

.project_container h4, .project_container p {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;   
    } 

.project_container:hover h4, .project_container:hover p {
    display:block;
    } 

.project_image {
    width: 100%;  
    }

.project_container:hover .project_text {
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: I also have a bit of the same problem in Firefox:
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/firefox_overlay_error.jpg

Comment: Looks fine on Windows (Chrome 33.0.1750.154)

Comment: Have you tried adding the image as background of the div instead of an img element inside the div (as you do it now)...? I had a similar issue and ended up solving it that way...

Comment: I suspect the outline, try using `outline:none;`, it's working fine on Windows Chrome so not much that I can help...